# Google Rest Apis and google sign in

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-fit-api

I've successfully used the google sign in library to create a google sign-in button, request additional scopes however I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate this into a API request. I'm using `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` and getting a token but I'm not sure how to translate this into an access token to send along with my API requests?

I'm using pretty much just what the documentation has:

```js
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    document.getElementById("acc").src = profile.getImageUrl();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    
    var oAuthToken = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token
    }
```

Comment: Should I even be using the google sign in for web to authorize oauth requests? Or should I use something else entirely like GAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID Token returned by Google Sign-In is not accepted as a credential for any Google APIs. It is intended only for [passing to your backend](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) so you can securely identify the user there.

You need an Access Token to call Google APIs. The token can be retrieved in your onSignIn method with `googleUser.getAuthResponse(true).access_token`. This will only be present if you've requested scopes other than basic profile scopes, which you'd need for API access anyway.

Google Sign-In is built on top of GAPI. Once the user is signed-in, you can check `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()` to verify the user is signed in, as far as GAPI is concerned. At this point, using [GAPI to call Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#callinganapi) will attach credentials to the request to Google's servers.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks a million, times over!